# how to root mean squared difference through a loop

Tags: python

I've just started learning python and I'm stuck on a practice problem.

root mean squared difference for 2 lists x and y is defined as the following, assuming n elements in both lists:

```
$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - b_i)^2}$
```

I have to create a function which calculates this. I've written the following but it is not right. Where am I going wrong, what is the shortest way to do this? I want to derive this function and not use numpy

```
import math
sumrmsd == 0
def rmsd(a,b):
    n = len(a)
    ninv = 1/n
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in range(0, len(a)+1):
            sumrmsd += (a[i] - b[i])**2
            x = math.sqrt(ninv*sumrmsd)
            return x
```

Comment: `len(a)+1` will cause an error. Say `len(a)` is 10, then the elements are `a[0]` through `a[9]`, so you want `range(10)`. (There are solutions here that don't use a range, but this is just to address the most immediate problem.)

Comment: Also, you only want to calculate and return `x` __after__ your loop, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

```
import math

def rmse(x, y):
    n = len(x)
    diff_sum = 0
    
    for i in range(n):
        diff = x[i] - y[i]
        diff_sum += diff**2
    
    rmse = math.sqrt(diff_sum/n)
    return rmse

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

result = rmse(x, y)
```

Output:

```
print(result)
```

Comment: “You can use the below code:”.  Why?  It would be useful to provide context as to *why* you believe this to be a viable solution, and how it corrects the OPs issue.

Answer (score 0):

`zip()`- You can use zip ***built-in function*** as both list contains **N elements**

**Code:**

```
def rmsd(x, y):
    sum_squares=0
    if len(x)==0: #edge case when there is an empty list.
        return 0 
    for _x,_y in zip(x,y): 
        sum_squares+=(_x-_y)**2
        
    return (sum_squares/len(x))**0.5

x=[5, 8, 2, 9, 7]
y=[6, 8, 1, 7, 9]

print("Root mean Square:",rmsd(x, y)) #Root mean Square: 1.4142135623730951
```

Answer (score 0):

this line

```py
sumrmsd += (a[i] - b[i])**2
```

will throw an error because the `i` variable will be greater than the length of the `a` list because this line

```py
for i in range(0, len(a)+1) # (0 ... i + 1)
```

I have fixed your code so that it will be a tidy function

```py
import math

def rmsd(a, b):
    n = len(a)
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        ninv = 1/n
        sumrmsd = 0
        for i in range(len(a)):
            sumrmsd += (a[i] - b[i])**2
    x = math.sqrt(ninv*sumrmsd)
    return x
```